# doing away with encoding in a genetic algorithmic impementation

Tags: encoding, genetic-algorithm

I was wondering if encoding in a genetic algorithm is really necessary , I mean let's say I have a program that is supposed to implement a GA to guess a word a user inputs,.

I don't see the point in having the chromosomes as a binary string, I would rather have it as just a string of letters , and mutate the string and crossbreed it accordingly.

Is such a approach unorthodox ? and will it really affect the outcome , or does it violate the definition of a genetic algorithm?

I do understand different types of encoding is possible.However that isn't what I am concerned about.Please keep your answer specific to the program objective of guessing a string that is similar to the one inputted by the user.

**THIS IS NOT A QUESTION ABOUT CHOICE OF ENCODING, BUT WHETHER I CAN DO AWAY WITH THE WHOLE ENCODING SCENARIO RELEVANT TO THIS QUESTION OBJECTIVE.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though unorthodox, your approach would be **perfectly valid**. The crossover and mutation functionalities may have to be tweaked however. There are in fact numerous such-non standard implementations (of encodings) today including alphabetic, alphanumeric, decimal, etc.

As per your specific case, if you do not encode an alphabetic chromosome, it is the same as encoding it in an alphabetic manner with an identity map; now, for an alphabetic encoding, the normal crossover functionality should be valid though the mutation may have to be so as to generate a random alphabet at the mutation site, if any.

Binary encoding in GA is generally followed only due to the **simplicity and speed** of the operations involved. For example, for your case, a string/character comparison takes longer to carry out in general considering the integer/boolean alternative.

Comment: Tailored to my question.Nice.